# checked first radio button as default using javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, radio-button

```
<input id="a" type="radio" name="radioButton">
<input id="b" type="radio" name="radioButton">
<input id="c" type="radio" name="radioButton">
<input id="d" type="radio" name="radioButton">
```

Lets say I have four radio buttons and how do I make the `first-child` to be `checked` as default by using just javascript, no jQuery please.

This is what I have done but did not work. Thanks in advance.

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name=radioButon]:first-child').checked = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your example wasn't working was because [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a [`NodeList` of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). You would need to iterate over each element in the list in order to set the `checked` property to `true`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gpo8hr80/)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[name=radioButton]:first-child');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el) { el.checked = true; });
```

---

Alternatively, you could also access the first matching element:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6voom9r8/)

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name=radioButton]')[0].checked = true;
// or..
document.querySelector('[name=radioButton]').checked = true;
```

---

<sub>*As a side note, you also had a typo.*</sub>

<sup>The attribute selector `[name=radioButon]` should have been `[name=radioButton]`.</sup>